# Unable to load 64-bit dll Error in C#

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-c++, dllimport

I have 64-bit c++ ddl, which I have to use in my c# application. I used it like

```
[DllImport("sampleDll.dll",
    EntryPoint = "sampleFunction",
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int sampleFunction(char[] ch, int i);
```

But when i try to run the application it shows error as

**"Unable to load DLL 'sampleDll.dll': The specified module could not be found."**

Iam using 64-bit OS. I tried by **copying the dll into System32 folder**

But still Iam getting the same error.

Please let me know the workaround for this problem........

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your C# process is 64 bit. If it's a 32 bit process, then you cannot load a 64 bit DLL, and that's the reason for the failure.

If you copied the file into `system32` then a 64 bit process will look there. If the file you copied is named `sampleDll.dll`, then your program will find it. So, if you see

```
Unable to load DLL 'sampleDll.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

the problem is not that `sampleDll.dll` cannot be located, rather that its dependencies cannot be resolved. The most common explanation for this is that you need to install the C runtime that `sampleDll.dll` depends upon. Consult the documentation for this DLL to find out what its dependencies are. If it's a DLL that you have made yourself, then you know what you used when you built it and can discern the dependencies for yourself.

Finally, I would stress that you should not be copying files into the `system32` directory. That belongs to the system and you should not touch it. The best place for a DLL to reside is in the same directory as the executable that loads it.

Comment: Just to add, you can add to this folder as well, being a 64bit dll c:\windows\SysWOW64. Though you should not do that!

Comment: @Abhinav No that's wrong. The 64 bit system directory is named `system32` and the 32 bit system directory is named `SysWOW64`. Somewhat confusing I know. So a 64 bit process can only see the 64 bit system directory, and a 32 bit process can only see the 32 bit system directory. The file system redirector takes care of that.

Comment: Oops my bad!, I completely confused between two folders. I would keep the comment here as a hint for others :)

Comment: Hi... I have try adding the dll in the same directory where the application is. But still same Error. Can you please send any link on how to find the dll dependency....

Comment: Where did you get the DLL from?

Comment: After the installation of an exe file - the folder in c:\Program files contains the dll. I have used that dll in my application

Comment: What does the documentation for the DLL say? Is it a DLL that you are meant to use, or is it private to this other app? You can use Dependency Walker to check out dependencies, but you ought to be doing this from the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Place your dll in the same folder where the applications is deployed.